# php mail with PDF attachment header causes to go into just mail

Tags: email, pdf, header, php

I have a webform that generates a PDF which is emailed to me upon submission but the email keeps getting filtered to the spam for folder.  I suspect that the something is wrong in the email header but not sure what it could be.

Any help is appreciated.

The following is a snippet...

```
// send by email
    $fileatt = '../pdfs/'.$filename;
    $fileatt_type = mime_content_type_manual($fileatt); // File Type  "application/pdf"
    $fileatt_name = $filename; // Filename that will be used for the file as the attachment 

    $email_from = "auth@mysite.com"; // Who the email is from 
    $email_subject = "Auth Report"; // The Subject of the email 

    //$email_to = "info@mysite.com";
    $email_to = "info@mysite.com";

    $headers = "From: ".$email_from; 

    $file = fopen($fileatt,'rb'); 
    $data = fread($file,filesize($fileatt)); 
    fclose($file); 

    $semi_rand = md5(time()); 
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . 
    "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . 
    " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

    $email_message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . 
    "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . 
    "Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . 
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . 
    $email_message .= "\n\n"; 

    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data)); 

    $email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . 
    "Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" . 
    " name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" . 
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . 
    $data .= "\n\n" . 
    "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add the sender of the email, which is **auth@mysite.com** for your case, as a new contact to the **address book** of your email client, then the email won't probably be marked as spam as it comes from a member of your contact address book.

Comment: Thanks but the email is sent to a number of people other than myself, marking the email as "not spam" does work however, I would need to ask everyone to do the same or add the address to their contact and that's just not a reasonable solution.  The server is not blacklisted so the email should be delivered in the inbox but something is wrong with the code and I'm not sure what it could be :/